# Kubernetes generating .yaml file full of f:

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Hi I used to generate kubernetes .yaml file from deployed applications, but recently I am getting a messy .yaml file. For instance:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-16T16:02:21Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    name: webapp
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:name: {}
      f:spec:
        f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector: {}
```

Can you see all the `f: etc..` ? What does that mean?

Is there a way to generate a simplified version of the deployed applications, pods and so on?

Without all the things not specified?

Used command was:

```
kubectl get deployments.apps webapp -o yaml > webapp.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your kubectl to v1.21 and above which does not include managed field by default. To see managed field again, append `--show-managed-fields` to your command.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Didn't know they were called `managed fields`